# Fundamental forms of a composite function

Tags: differential-geometry

So I have to work out the three fundamental forms, the principal and Gaussian curvatures for this surface element...

I have to use the function:

$f(u_1,...,u_n)$ = $(u_1,...,u_n, F(u))$ where F is a differential function of $u = (u_1,...,u_n)$

I know how to do it with X's and Y's for example $f = (x , y , x^2 + y^2)$

but I'm stuck on the $(u_1,...,u_n)$ part... 
Can some help get me started? thanks

Comment: It's the very same thing, except that you deal with $n$ parameters and dimension $n+1$ instead of just $2$ parameters and dimension $3$. This means that instead of $f_x$ and $f_y,$ you now have $f_{u_1},\ldots,f_{u_n}.$ From these you can compute the first fundamental form exactly as in the familiar case with two parameters and dimension $3.$

Comment: @jflipp So you say I can still you 2 parameters and dimension 3... Would my parameters be $u_1$ and $u_n$? Then I would start off by taking the partials of $u_1$ and $u_n$?

Comment: If you have another problem, I think it's best to ask another question. That's how this site is organized.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started.

We consider the hypersurface element given by the parametrization $f(u_1,\ldots,u_n) = (u_1,\ldots,u_n,F(u_1,\ldots,u_n)).$ We put $u := (u_1,\ldots,u_n).$

Let's fix a parameter value $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n).$ Then the tangent space at the hypersurface element in the point $f(v)$ is spanned by the vectors $f_{u_1}(v),\ldots,f_{u_n}(v).$ We compute
$$f_{u_j}(v) = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0,F_{u_j}(v)) \qquad for\ j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
where the $1$ is in the $j$-th coordinate.

With this basis of the tangent space at $v,$ the first fundamental form is given by
$$
g_{ij} = \langle f_{u_i},f_{u_j}\rangle \qquad for\ i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes Euclidean scalar product in $\mathbb R^{n+1}.$

For the given parametrization we calculate $g_{ii} = 1+F_{u_i}(v)^2$ and $g_{ij} = F_{u_i}(v)F_{u_j}(v).$

The normal direction of the hypersurface element at $v$ is the unique direction orthogonal to all the $f_{u_i}.$

Can you continue?

Comment: Yes! thanks you!!!